# $guess command in discord.py...but I have a problem

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I've been trying to make a $guess command for the past 2 days now where you guess a number between 1 to 10, but it never worked. Here's the code.

```
import discord
import random
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import MissingPermissions

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "$")

colors = [0xFFFFFF, 0x000000, 0x0000ff, 0x008000, 0xFFFF00, 0xff0000, 0x00ffff, 0x00FF00, 0xffa500, 0xFF69B4, 0x654321, 0xFF00FF, 0xF5F5DC, 0x800000, 0xFF8C00]

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot is ready')
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Game("$help"), afk = False)

    @client.command()
    async def guess(ctx):
    
        user = ctx.message.author
    
        selection = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]
    
        number = (random.choice(selection))
    
        em = discord.Embed(title = None, description = None,color = (random.choice(colors)))
    
        em.add_field(name = "Guess the number", value = "Guess the number I'm thinking of right now!")
    
        await ctx.send(embed = em)
    
        @client.event
        async def on_message(message):
    
            if(ctx.message.author == user):
    
                em = discord.Embed(title = None, description = None,color = (random.choice(colors)))
    
                if any(word in message.content for word in number):
    
                    em.add_field(name = "You Won!", value = f"You guessed the correct number! I was thinking of {number}.")
    
                else:
    
                    em.add_field(name = "You Lost!", value = f"You guessed the incorrect number. I was thinking of {number}.")
    
                await ctx.send(embed = em)
                pass
    
            elif(ctx.message.author == client):
```

Also in the last line, at "elif(ctx.message.author == client):", I didn't know what to put.
And when I used the command, it spammed the You Lost embed in the chat. I had to stop the code repeatedly to stop the spamming.

[image]

Please help.

Disclaimer:
I am new to discord.py -- be gentle.

Answer (score 1):

Well this is a bad way to do this with `on_message` event. You should do it with `wait_for` Here is code I've made for you:

```
@client.command()
async def guesss(ctx):

    numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    numb = random.choice(numbers)
    print(numb)

    await ctx.send(f'Guess the number, 1 - 10')
        
    msg = await client.wait_for('message')
    if msg.content == f'{numb}':
        await ctx.send('Correct!')
    else:
        await ctx.send(f'Incorrect i was thinking of {numb}')
```

With this code bod will print correct number so if you want to check the correct number just look at your terminal and there you go.